# I am trying to get a list of objects to pass to my screen, but I keep getting a type cast error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, jsonserializer

Here is my `Product` class:

```
class Product {
  int? id ;
  String? shop_id;
  String? category_id;
  String? sub_cat_id;
  String? product_title;
  String? product_Description;
  String? product_image;
  int? product_price;
  int? discount;
  int? quantity;
  int? uom_id;
  String? in_stock;
  String? status;
  String? created_at;
  String? updated_at;
  String? imagename;
  String? store_name;
  String? uom_name;

  Product({required this.id, required this.shop_id,this.category_id,this.sub_cat_id, this.product_title,
    this.product_Description,this.product_image,this.product_price, this.discount, this.quantity, this.uom_id, this.in_stock,
    this.created_at, this.updated_at, this.imagename, this.store_name, this.uom_name
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(id: json['id'] as int, shop_id: json['shop_id'] as String,category_id: json['category_id'] as String,sub_cat_id: json['sub_cat_id'] as String,product_title: json['product_title'] as String,
        product_Description: json['product_Description'] as String, product_image:json['product_image'] as String, product_price: json['product_price']as int,
        discount: json['discount'] as int, quantity: json['quantity'] as int, uom_id: json['uom_id'] as int, in_stock: json['in_stock'] as String,
        created_at: json['created_at'] as String, updated_at: json['updated_at'] as String, imagename: json['store_name'] as String, uom_name: json['uom_name']as String,
    );
  }
}
```

My function to return a list of products is

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {



http.Response response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(productUrl + 'product_details/8'),
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token'
  },
);



Product user = Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['data']);
print(user.toString());
final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];

final extractedData = json.decode(response.body)['data'];


extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {

  print('about to add');

  loadedProducts.add(Product(
    id: int.parse(prodId),
    shop_id: prodData.shop_id,
    category_id: prodData['category_id'],
    sub_cat_id: prodData['sub_cat_id'],
    product_title: prodData['product_title'],
    product_Description:prodData['product_Description'],
    product_image:prodData['product_image'],
    product_price: prodData['product_price'],
    discount: prodData['discount'],
    quantity: prodData['quantity'],
    uom_id: prodData['uom_id'],
    in_stock: prodData['in_stock'],
    created_at: prodData['created_at'],
    updated_at: prodData['updated_at'],
    imagename: prodData['store_name'],
    uom_name: prodData['uom_name'],

  ));
});
print(loadedProducts.length);

List products = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];


return jsonDecode(response.body)['data'].map((product) => Product.fromJson(product)).toList();



 }
```

I am trying to parse data from a remote API, and then convert the JSON data to a list of products. I keep getting the error

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One of your datas type is String and you're trying to assign that to int. If you share on which line you're getting error then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `as` use `int.tryParse` to all int field like,

```dart
id: int.tryParse("${json['id']}"),
```

Answer (score 0):

the (int) could be null, so instead of parse use tryParse. and if it

Example:

```
 int.tryParse("${json['id']}"),
```